# Removing paragraphs from footnote [ms-word]

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

In my work, I have a footnote in which there are 3 "enters" before first footnote (marked in red in attached screenshot) that I am not able to select or delete. Does anybody know how to remove these 3 paragraphs? As this is on all pages, I guess it has to be something in pre-formatting of Footnotes in Word but cannot find what.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra paragraph breaks have probably been added as part of the format of the footnote area separator, as you guessed. In that case, you can remove them like this:

1. On the **View** tab, in the **Views** group, click **Draft**.
2. In the body of your document, double-click one of the footnote numbers (or, on the **References** tab, in the **Footnotes** group, click **Show Notes**) to open the footnote editing pane.

   [image: Footnote editing pane]
3. On the drop-down menu, click **Footnote Separator**.
4. The separator line and the extra paragraph breaks below it will be shown. Delete the extra paragraph breaks. Alternatively, click **Reset** – though this will also reset any other changes that have been made to the separator (for example, if the color of the separator line was changed).

   [image: Footnotes Separator view and Reset button]
5. On the **View** tab, in the **Views** group, click **Print Layout** to return to Print Layout view.

Comment: That's correct, You are right! Thank you very much!